# Node + Express with static HTML. How to route all requests to index.html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a single page web app using Node + Express and Handlebars for templating. Everything currently works well from index.html, which is served from a pretty standard server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');

var server = express();
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var port = 10001;
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

This works perfectly when loading from `http://localhost:10001/`. My issue is that I'm using push states in the app, so the browser may show a URL like `http://localhost:10001/foo/bar` and then if I refresh the page, I get the error `Cannot GET /foo/bar` since there is no route for this.

So my question, and pardon my incredible noobishness when it comes to Node, can I make it so all requests route to index.html? The JavaScript in my app can handle showing the right content based on URL params on page load. I don't want to define custom routes as the number would be large, and the paths for them can change dynamically.

Answer (score 60):

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()

/* route requests for static files to appropriate directory */
server.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/static-files-dir'))

/* other routes defined before catch-all */
server.get('/some-route', (req, res) => {
  res.send('ok')
})

/* final catch-all route to index.html defined last */
server.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

const port = 8000;
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('server listening on port ' + port)
})
```

Comment: It is good to **note** that the catch-all route should be after the static middleware and other get routes, as pointed out in other answers.

Comment: what is the use for public in => "server.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));" . Can that be used in later steps to alias  "__dirname + '/public' " , while serving individual files with specified route name ?

Answer (score 11):

This pattern will serve static assets before hitting the catch-all route that serves up your front-end application. To register any additional routes, just add them above the catch-all route.

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();

// middleware
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// routes
server.use('*', function (req, res) {
  // serve file
});

var port = 10001;
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Hey, just wanted to point out that you're importing `static` but never actually using it since you do `express.static`

Comment: @kemicofa great catch! Fixed!

Answer (score 8):

```
var app = express();

var options = {
  dotfiles: 'ignore',
  etag: true,
  extensions: ['htm', 'html'],
  index: 'index.html',
  lastModified: true,
  maxAge: '1d',
  setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
    res.set('x-timestamp', Date.now());
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=1d');
  }
};

app.use(compression());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public', options));
app.use('*', express.static(__dirname + '/public', options));
```

Answer (score 8):

This short thing works well:

```
import express from "express";

const app = express(),
      staticServe = express.static(`${ __dirname }/public`);

app.use("/", staticServe);
app.use("*", staticServe);
```

Just make sure that all URLs from your HTML/JS files are absolute now, as all resources that do not exist will return `index.html` file.

`Express v 4.15.2`

Answer (score 3):

```
var express = require('express');

var server = express();
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

server.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

var port = 10001;
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: This works, with the edit I made, except it also acts on the URL for my CSS file, so it serves index.html instead of the CSS file. Is there a way to only apply this by mime type (ie, only on html).

Comment: @JPollock register middleware for public files before your catch-all route. That way requests to css/js will be picked up before your index route.