# How to handle Express JS and Angular JS routes together?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes, ngroute

I am working on a web application using Express, Angularjs. I have a main page (i.e index.html) that i want to serve on express. The code for the server is written in `xpressServer.js`.

```
// file tree
->controller
---formController.js
->js
---app.js
->node_modules
->views
---form.html
---home.html
-index.html
-package.json
-xpressServer.js
```

The above is the file structure of my application.

```
// xpressServer.js
var express = require('express'); 
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/js')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/controller')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views')));

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/assets/view/index.html'));
});

app.listen(8081, function() {
    console.log('listenin on port 8081');
});
```

And, my `index.html` is

```
// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="formModule">
    <head>
        <base href="/" />  
        <title>dfgadfggth</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>       
    </head>
    <body>
       <div ng-view></div>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

what exactly do i want to do?

I want to serve the `index.html` using Express routing and then route using angularjs.`<div ng-view></div>`.I want to grab a view depending on the route and then place it in `ng-view` present in the `index.html`.

The code for the `app.js` that handles angular routing is:

```
// app.js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module("formModule",['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,   $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: '/views/home.html'
        })
        .when('/form', {
            templateUrl: '/views/form.html',
            controller: '/controller/formController.js'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
}]);
```

I have been searching for the solution but couldn't find one that worked for me. Kindly help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you're using client side routing, you basically need to make all URLs serve `index.html` - that way you don't get a 404 error if you try to navigate straight to one of the views/refresh the page. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349497/node-express-with-static-html-how-to-route-all-requests-to-index-html

Comment: `app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/assets/view/index.html'));
    });`    Should i change it this way?

Comment: Something along those lines would probably work, yes :) Just make sure your catch-all route is the last one you define in your Express app, otherwise it'll override your other routes (like your static assets, etc.)

Comment: I have tried the same thing, but it didn't work!