# Vue/Webpack + Express (MEVN): URLs for API calls, development vs production

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, vue.js

Building a MEVN application.

When running in my development environment, there are two servers running concurrently: webpack-dev-server at `localhost:8080` serving up the Vue/Webpack-based front-end client application, and `localhost:8081` serving the Node+Express back-end application which provides the RESTful endpoints that the client consumes.

When deploying for production, however, the Node+Express server, in addition to providing those endpoints, also serves the static Vue/Webpack application as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349497/node-express-with-static-html-how-to-route-all-requests-to-index-html).

My issue is this: To call one of those endpoints from the client in the production environment, since they're all coming from the same server, I can just load `/route/to/my/endpoint?param=val` or similar. In the dev environment, since they're two separate servers, I'd load `http://localhost:8081/route/to/my/endpoint?param=val` instead.

It seems like there must be some trivial way to include the `http://localhost:8081` in the code when running the webpack-dev-server, but omit it when building for deployment.

I've seen a few articles talking about the `publicPath` webpack config item, but none of them are quite addressing this issue in a way that makes sense to me.

What's the "right way" to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out a bit more quickly than I expected to.

An easy way to do this is with Webpack's `definePlugin` mechanism, which is nicely described [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

Essentially, in the `plugins` section of my `webpack.dev.conf.js` I added this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __API__: "'http://localhost:8081'"
}),
```

and in the same section of `webpack.prod.conf.js` I added this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __API__: "''"
}),
```

Then, in a vue file, when I wanted to hit an endpoint, the call would look like this:

```
axios.get(__API__ + '/myendpoint')
```

Critical thing that's mentioned in the above article but easy to miss: The webpack engine does exact text replacement of the identifier, in this case, `__API__`, and since my code there is expecting a string, it must be defined in the DefinePlugin so it's got quotes around it. An alternate way to do this would be `__API__: JSON.stringify("http://localhost:8081")` or similar.