# Unable to open angular build application from node server

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I built an app on angular 6 and  directly able to open index.html from dist folder but when i tried it opening from my node server, error is coming in console as:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
styles.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
vendor.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

with line 1 as < ! doctype html >

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist')));
app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/ang-node/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port,(req,res)=>{
    console.log(`server started on port ${port} `);
});
```

Comment: Your app is sending back `index.html` when the browser is requesting your javascript files. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349497/node-express-with-static-html-how-to-route-all-requests-to-index-html

Comment: index.html will come on the sendFile request, in the middleware i am passing the static path of the parent directory. The file is getting up in the sources but in the console some errors are coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error you may not configured the right public directory for the angular, Try this,

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist/ang-node/public'))); // <== correct public directory here
app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/ang-node/index.html')); // <== Make sure this is dist/ang-node not dist
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port,(req,res)=>{
    console.log(`server started on port ${port} `);
});
```