# nodejs route refresh issue Cannot Get /

Tags: node.js, angular

i am serving my Angular 7 project at nodejs server , on page refresh i get error Cannot GET /profile for example .

i have read that i need to add this code to allow server to load routs on refresh  , and it worked but another issue showed up that my node Post or Get rquests stoped working because any route will always redirect to my main domain for example www.domain.com/api/profile will redirect to www.domain.com and the request function will not fire . any idea what to do?

note: if i remove the below code , request will work but refresh issue will show up .

```
 app.get('*', function (req, res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/build/dist/index.html'));
 });
```

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26638143/10747134

Comment: Yessss it worked !! thanks , post as answer please

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if I should post that as an answer, or if this should be called a duplicate-
Sorry still new to how SO works with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node + Express with static HTML. How to route all requests to index.html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349497/node-express-with-static-html-how-to-route-all-requests-to-index-html)

Comment: haha its ok , my issue was , i was calling the code above before my Get request thats why it was not working , now after adding it after all my ReseAPI requests it works fine . thanks

Comment: No problem- happy coding!

Comment: This code should be below your node route code. For eg. router.get/use('api') should be above this router.get('*') code.

Answer (score 4):

Solved after adding this code after all my route requests ( GET , POST , etc) Not Before.

```
// other routes defined before catch-all 
server.get('/some-route', (req, res) => {
  res.send('ok')
});

// final catch-all route to index.html defined last 
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```