# Angular 8 - build production routes doesn't work

Tags: angular

Hello i'm deploying an app in Angular 8, when i work in dev , all works well even the routes but when i run "ng build --prod", it generates the build in /dist and i upload  the aplication to the server, the index work fine but when i execute an href to a page (example: /login) i get not found page.

here are my routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: FullIndexComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: FullLoginComponent }
];
```

this only happens in production build, and i need to upload the build because i am working with cpanel.

thank you

Comment: Which technology are you using in the backend? how are you bundling your frontend and backend? I am pretty sure the issue is that the route is interpreted by the backend and not angular, you can solve that in your backend by redirecting all unmapped API calls to index.html

Comment: In the backend i'm using express.js and they dont have relation at all ,  the frontend is in Agular  8, the api works well, the problem is the routes , as you can see in the question i declare the routes in the file app-routing.module.ts and they work fine in dev but  no in production. if you have any idea can you show me how?

Comment: @YeisonM the problem is not the routes, as h0ss said, the issue is your backend server configuration, which needs to redirect to `index.html`

Comment: @YeisonM try this in your backend, it will solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349497/node-express-with-static-html-how-to-route-all-requests-to-index-html

Comment: thank you , but the backend is in a different server to frontend and even in different port. i can't use  the API way, and i think that Angular can work by  his own

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of the routes using

```
<li><a class="btn button_menu" routerLink="/login">Acceder</a></li>
```

instead of

```
<li><a class="btn button_menu" href="/login">Acceder</a></li>
```

and the problem of th refresh configuring useHash in the app-routing.module.ts , like this :

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
```